# Read log file with SplFileObject Class and flag SKIP_EMPTY not work

Tags: php, spl, splfileobject

I need to read some rsync log files, and these have some empty lines

I try to use:

```
$f = new \SplFileObject($file);

$f->setFlags(7); // Test 6 value and same problem

   while (!$f->eof())
   {
     // Do something
     // But $f->fgets() show any empty "" line

   }
```

According with [manual](http://php.net/manual/es/class.splfileobject.php#splfileobject.constants.skip-empty)

```
/* Constantes */
const integer DROP_NEW_LINE = 1 ;
const integer READ_AHEAD = 2 ;
const integer SKIP_EMPTY = 4 ;
const integer READ_CSV = 8 ;
```

What it's wrong on my code?

Comment: Line `Esto requiere que la bandera READ_AHEAD esté activada para que funcione como se tenía previsto.` tells you something?

Comment: 4+2+1 = 7 -> `$f->setFlags(7);`Not valid?